# eval(): can't assign to function call

Tags: eval, python-3.2

Yet another question for my cookie clicker...
Here is the code I made that produces an error:

```
cps=cps+bcps[buych]
c=c-bprice[buych]
eval(buych)=eval(buych)+1
```

cps is a variable,
c is a variable,
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 are variables
buych is a string (Which I get from an input() command)
bcps and bprice are maps (shown below)

```
bcps = {"b1":'1',
    "b2":'5',
    "b3":'10',
    "b4":'20',
    "b5":'25'}
bprice = {"b1":'10',
    "b2":'20',
    "b3":'30',
    "b4":'40',
    "b5":'50'}
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve is:
-Take the input string value, which will be 'b1','b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'
-Increase cps buy it's value within bcps
-Decrease c by it's value within bprice
-Use eval to convert the 'b#' to b#
-Increase b# by 1

When running the script, I do not get error text in the python shell. Instead, I get a pop-up that says "Can't assign to function call". The error is highlighted as the first white space before the eval(). I really don't get this, as I have no functions within the error.

Thanks for reading,
 Cookie Monster

Comment: `eval()` is a function. You're trying to assign to the result of calling `eval(buych)`.

Comment: huh, didn't realize. Do I convert the result of eval into something else?

Comment: Imagine if the code was simplified, such that `eval(..)` is `f()`, then the resulting simplified code is `f()=f()` which won't work for the exact same reason: functions are not variables/properties and *cannot* be used on the left of the assignment operator. However, **don't use eval** for this - for this assignment simply *forget* it exists. Instead, access the dictionaries ("maps") by key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval(buych)` is a function call -- you're calling the function `eval()`. You can only assign to variables, you can't assign to the result of a function.

You need to concatenate the variable into a valid assignment expression, and `exec` that:

```
exec(buych + '=' + buych + '+1')
```

`eval` is for evaluating expressions, you have to use `exec` to execute a whole statement.

But if you find yourself needing to do this, you're usually doing something wrong. Instead of computing variable names and expressions, you should use lists or dicts so you can refer to them using an index or key.

Comment: eval does not seem to support the statements with '='. I think we would rather need to use `exec` than `eval`

Comment: @DakshShah Thanks, fixed